# How to explicitly type an argument as a function in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to make sure that the 3rd argument passed to my function is a function itself. How can I set up that explicit type?

The below example is what I want to do where the operator is actually a mathematical function like +,%,^, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say it is best to just avoid explicitly annotation that argument with a type. While there is a `Function` abstract type in Julia, any object can potentially be callable using call overloading.

Comment: Is there a situation where you would want to explicitly type it? Would it ever help performance?

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly typing an argument as a function in Julia is the same as a regular explicit type.

A quick example will look like the following where operator is explicitly typed as a function:

```
julia> function math(numOne::Int64, numTwo::Int64, operator::Function)
    operator(numOne, numTwo)
end

julia> math(1, 1, +)
2

julia> math(3, 2, ^)
9

julia> math(3, 2, 3)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching math(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  math(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Function) at REPL[9]:2
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[13]:1
```

Comment: Not all functions are <:Function. Also, this changes the optimization behavior.

Comment: Feel free to edit to make my answer more complete as I am not Familiar with how this changes the behavior.

Comment: However note that not all "callable" objects in Julia have a type that is a subtype of `Function`. One most notable example are Python functions coming from the `PyCall.jl` package, and probably also type constructors. Thus, it's usually not a good idea to restrict the type to `Function`